# How to call one controller to another controller URL in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi I am new to Spring MVC ,I want to call method from one controller to another controller ,how can I do that .please check my code below

```
@Controller

    @RequestMapping(value="/getUser")
    @ResponseBody
    public User getUser()
    {
        User u = new User();
        //Here my dao method is activated and I wil get some userobject
       return u;
    }
   @Controller

    @RequestMapping(value="/updatePSWD")
    @ResponseBody
    public String updatePswd()
    {
        here I want to call above controller method and 
       I want to update that user password here.
       how can  I do that 
        return "";
    }
```

any one help me .

Comment: you shouldn't call another controller method, move the logic to a service class

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You never have to put business logic into the controller, and less business logic related with database, the transactionals class/methods should be in the service layer. But if you need to redirect to another controller method use redirect

```
@RequestMapping(value="/updatePSWD")
@ResponseBody
public String updatePswd()
{
  return "redirect:/getUser.do";
}
```

Comment: How to call in case getUser(String destURL) method takes argument?

Answer (score 15):

Can do like this:

```
@Autowired
private MyOtherController otherController;

@RequestMapping(value = "/...", method = ...)
@ResponseBody
public String post(@PathVariable String userId, HttpServletRequest request) {
    return otherController.post(userId, request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A controller class is a Java class like any other. Although Spring does clever magic for you, using reflection to examine the annotations, *your* code can call methods just as normal Java code:

```
 public String updatePasswd()
 {
    User u = getUser();
    // manipulate u here
    return u;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should place method getUser in a service (example UserService class) .

In the getUser controller, you call method getUser in the Service to get the User

Similarly, in the updatePswd controller, you call method getUser in the Service ,too

Answer (score 0):

Here no need to add **@reponseBody** annotation as your redirecting to another controller
Your code will look like

```
@Controller
class ControlloerClass{

        @RequestMapping(value="/getUser",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @ResponseBody
        public User getUser(){
            User u = new User();
            //Here my dao method is activated and I wil get some userobject
            return u;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/updatePSWD",method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String updatePswd(){
           //update your user password
           return "redirect:/getUser";
        }

}
```