# How can i use a RestControler function in another RestControler

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I get org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException when i call SaleRestService in ProductRestService like in the code below.

How can i do it properly?

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class ProductRestService {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;
    @Autowired
    public SaleRestService saleRestService ; 

    @RequestMapping(value="/productQuatityMinusOne", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public void ProductQuatityMinusOne(@RequestParam(name="id") Long id){
        Product p = productRepository.findProductById(id);
        double salePrice = p.getPrice();
        Date now = new java.util.Date();
        Sale s = new Sale(id,salePrice,now);
        saleRestService .saveOneSale(s);
        p.setId(id);
        int q = p.getQuantity()-1;
        p.setQuantity(q);
        productRepository.save(p);
    }
}

@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class SaleRestService {

    @Autowired
    private SaleRepository saleRepository; 

    //Save one sale
    @RequestMapping(value="/saveOneSale", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public Sale saveOneSale(@RequestBody Sale s){
         return saleRepository.save(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call one controller to another controller URL in Spring MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949846/how-to-call-one-controller-to-another-controller-url-in-spring-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be calling your controllers from one another.

Two solutions:

- Put the code of the saveOneSale in another @Service, and call that from your @RestControllers
- You could redirect the http call of ProductQuatityMinusOne in ProductRestService  to saveOneSale in SaleRestService  by using a spring boot redirect, like this `return "redirect:/saveOneSale";`, but I dont know if that will work because you'd be redirecting to a POST handler.

Personlly I'd do the first solution:

- remove @RestController from SaleRestService
- create a SaleRestController class, anotate it with @RestController, and put a method with the following annotation:  @RequestMapping(value="/saveOneSale", method=RequestMethod.POST)
- in that method, call SaleRestService.saveOneSale

Everything should just work (TM)